# leaflet.js consuming lot of cpu memory after many zooms and play arounds

Tags: leaflet

Please go through below basic leaflet code. After many zooms and pull around map its consuming lot of CPU memory.

How can I clear memory after each zoom level.

Please help me out on this.

```
<link href="css/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>

    <style>
        #map {
            height: 1080px;
            width:1920;
        }
    </style>   
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
            L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '© <a>ABCDEFG</a>',
                minZoom: 4,
                maxZoom: 11,                
            }).addTo(map);
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Add any tiles path and open cpu usage from task manager. Start zooming now and then drag few areas you will see CPU USAGE count increasing. Is there a way to reduce memory usage?

Comment: You're going to have difficulty getting help with the current state of your question. Here's a few things that you should edit in that would help. CPU and Memory are not the same thing; is it CPU or Memory? How did you detect the issue? How do you know that it is leaflet? Additionally, posting info from the Chrome devtools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling would help.